# Smali file is corrupted after writing with fputs()

Tags: c, file, getline, smali, fputs

Goal : i want to inject a one line code in smali

**My current approach**

I am reading smali file with **getline()** and writing whole content to a new file with some changes.

Here is code

```
while(getline(&line,&line_size,smaliFile) != -1) {
        if (FLAG) {
            if (strstr(line,"return-void") != NULL) {
                fputs("    invoke-static {}, Lcom/hax/util/MainService;->start()V\n\n",smali_tmp);
                fputs("    return-void\n",smali_tmp);
                FLAG=0;
                continue;
            }
        }
        fputs(line,smali_tmp);
    }

    if (FLAG) {
        fprintf(stderr,"can't find hook point !\n");
        exit(1);
    }
```

Where **smaliFile** is original smali file and **smali_tmp** is new patched smali file.

And if i am doing same thing manually then it's recompiling as expected

Here is error while recompiling

```
Smali.smali[1771,7] mismatched input '' expecting END_METHOD_DIRECTIVE         
Could not smali file: com/gbwhatsapp/Smali.smali
```

But when i am looking into corrupted file at location 1771,7 with vim , there is no any unusual thing or character present.

I also used diff command to check changes and diff outputs only one line which was added by me.

Comment: Examine your file with hex viewer to see that there are no non-printable characters or something

Comment: Ok i will try .